# How can I merge the output of two amost identical powershell commands?

Tags: powershell

I'm monitoring the counnection count for each of my CAS servers and would like to concatenate the output of each of them so I can display it cleanly.

I've tried "adding" the results as in $rpc = $rpc + XXXCommandHereXXX, and piping as illustrated below, but I'm unable to "join" the commands.

```
 $rpc = (get-counter -ComputerName NYCEXCAS01 -Counter "RPC/HTTP Proxy\Current Number of Incoming RPC over HTTP Connections").countersamples  | Select-Object Path, CookedValue 
 $rpc | (get-counter -ComputerName NYCEXCAS02 -Counter "RPC/HTTP Proxy\Current Number of Incoming RPC over HTTP Connections").countersamples  | Select-Object Path, CookedValue
```

Am I trying to do something that is logically unreasonable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't perform the `Select-Object` on each `Get`.  You should then have no problem "adding" the collections and `Select`ing the desired properties later:

```
$a = (get-counter -ComputerName NYCEXCAS01 -Counter "RPC/HTTP Proxy\Current Number of Incoming RPC over HTTP Connections").countersamples
$b = (get-counter -ComputerName NYCEXCAS02 -Counter "RPC/HTTP Proxy\Current Number of Incoming RPC over HTTP Connections").countersamples
$rpc = $a + $b
$rpc | Select-Object -Property Path, CookedValue
```

You could also just gather all the `Get-Counter` results, *then* `Select` the `CounterSample`s, then perform a `Select` for `Path`, `CookedValue`.